# How to hide and unhide a specific file or folder in Windows with Python

Tags: python, file, hide

I want to open a file/folder using Python (I know how to do this) but then hide the file/folder after.

**How can I hide and unhide specific files or folders in Python?**

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the OS being used. On windows there is a `Hidden` filesystem attribute you can set in files:

```
def hide_file(filename):
    import win32file
    import win32con
    import win32api
    flags = win32file.GetFileAttributesW(filename)
    win32file.SetFileAttributes(filename, 
        win32con.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN | flags)
```

On unix/linux the hidden files are the ones that start with a dot "`.`". You can just rename the file:

```
def hide_file(filename):
    import os
    os.rename(filename, os.path.join(
        os.path.dirname(filename), 
        '.' + os.path.basename(filename))
    )
```

Comment: but it won't hide from apps and windows search. Just from the file explorer